# Find column in separate table

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got table A with column X. Column X SHOULD exist within table B too, however, the name of table B is unknown to me.

Is there a way of finding table B?

I am using an Oracle database and SQL Developer. I cannot see anything of help in the contraints/dependencies sections of table A. I suspect the relationship between column X and table B is taken care of by the application interacting with the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following:

```
select *
from dba_tab_columns
where column_name = 'COLUMN_X'
  and table_name != 'TABLE_A'
```

You could even study all procedures, package, triggers, etc using your column, to understand the way they manipulate the data in your column; to find these objects, try:

```
select NAME, TYPE, OWNER
from dba_source
where upper(text) like '%COLUMN_X%'
```

Comment: Good idea, but what if column X is named differently in table B? It will most likely be an ID column in table B.

Comment: This way I can't see a solution different from scanning all the columns of all the tables to check if the values are the same that your column, but this could be more an exercise than something to do on a real DataBase

Comment: You could even check the DataBase source to understand how your column is used; just edited my answer to give an help finding these objects

Answer (score 0):

DBA_TAB_COLUMNS Table describes columns of all tables,view and clusters in the database. Refer Oracle Documentation. Both DBA_TAB_COLUMNS and ALL_TAB_COLUMNS provide similar information while ALL_TAB_COLUMNS provide info as accessible to the current user

Refer Oracle Documentation - 
 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4146.htm#REFRN23277

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm#I1020277